# winforms wcf application works in Visual Studio but not from EXE

Tags: .net, winforms, wcf, visual-studio-2012, deployment

I have created a winforms application using a WCF DataService.

The application runs in the Visual Studio IDE, but it does not run from the debug.exe

On my app.config I have this endpoint:

```
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/DataService/Service1/"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
```

When I run the application from the exe, I get the message that

"There was no endpoint listening at

```
http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/DataService/Service1
```

that could accept the message."

How can I deploy the service on the machine so the exe can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Design_Time_Addresses is a project that's part of the same solution, and so Visual Studio will be hosting this service for you when you start your client.

So when you run the client outside of Visual Studio you'll need to host the Design_Time_Addresses service in IIS and point the client's config to that instance of the service.

See here for how to deploy an IIS-Hosted WCF Service
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is there a way to run an application like this without using IIS?  I am hoping to deploy to a Windows server that is not a web server.